# Ruby/Rails 4 - Satisfy a Specific Condition

Tags: ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have the following table structure:

```
Questions    
 * id
 * prompt

 Options    
 * id
 * name
 * image

 Question Assignments     # Acts as a join table for the tables above and holds #
                          # a boolean of whether an option is "correct" or not. #
 * question_id
 * option_id
 * correct
```

And let's say we have the current information stored in the database:

```
Question:
  id: 4
  prompt: "Please select the green pictures.  Choose 3."

 Question_assignments: 
  option_id: 1
  question_id: 4
  correct: true

  option_id: 2
  question_id: 4
  correct: false

  option_id: 3
  question_id: 4
  correct: true

  option_id: 4
  question_id: 4
  correct: false
```

In order to achieve a "correct" answer, the user would have to exclusively submit only options **1** and **3**.  Any other combination of submitted options would be incorrect.

**My question is:**  How do I iterate and evaluate, user-submitted answers, whether or not the overall question is correct?

For example, a user might submit the following (which would be a 'wrong' answer based on the scenario above):

```
 'question_id' => 4
 'option_ids[]' => [1, 2, 4]
```

The logic I am thinking would be something like:

1. Find all correct answers based on question_id (4) : which would
   return '1' and '3'
2. Iterate through user-submitted values, see if it equals '1' or '3'
3. Then not sure what to do from here??

Hopefully this make sense, as it can be difficult to articulate.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be: fetch correct options for question 4, insert these options into an array, say `correct_options` then check:

```
if option_ids.sort == correct_options.sort
  puts "Correct answer!"
else
  puts "Sorry, wrong answer :("
end
```

If you sort both arrays and compare them, you can check if they are equal.